# Angular dependency injection in $resource factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

A doubt about DI on factory resource:

AFAIK the below sample is the recommended way to inject dependencies in Angular1:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Resource', Resource);

Resource.$inject = ['$resource', 'CONSTANTS'];

function Resource($resource, CONSTANTS) {
  return $resource(CONSTANTS.server_url + '/resource/:id');
}
```

But I'm having problems in use it combined with the new keyword in my Controller:

```
var resource = new Resource();
```

This results in an error saying that CONSTANTS is undefined. Using the below syntax, it works normally.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Resource', ['$resource', 'CONSTANTS', function($resource, CONSTANTS) {
  return $resource(CONSTANTS.server_url + '/resource/:id');
}]);
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Why are you instantiating `Resource` yourself using `new`? You're supposed to have it injected into your controller.

Comment: I'm actually injecting it on my controller and instantiating it with new keyword to use it's methods like $save. The documentation mentions it as a possible way to have an object from its type.

Comment: Then you'll have to show how you're injecting it exactly…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular's injections system only works if you're using Angular's injection system. By doing `new Resource()`, you're instantiating a plain Javascript "class" yourself using plain Javascript; the `$inject` property on `Resource` doesn't magically do anything in this case.

What you're doing with `module(..).factory('Resource', ..)` is to define `'Resource'` as an injectable dependency. You must now use this as a dependency for your controller, and Angular will work its injection system:

```
module(..).controller('MyController', ['Resource', function (Resource) {
    Resource.get(...)
}]);
```